# Isthere a way in R to create a variable that was the sum of variable of a data frame conditioned with a variable in the first dataframe?

Tags: r

Hello I'm new in R and in databases, and I am having problem joining  two databases.

Let me explain, I have two databases

The first one (called m) have the following variables

> Entity     Code     Hour
>   a          3024            8:00
>   b          3024            8:05
>   c          2111            8:11
>   d          2111            8:18
>   e          2111            8:33
>   f          2111            8:50
>   g          2111            9:08

the second one called m2 have the following variables

> Total    Hour2 
>   102     7:55 
>   5000    7:58 
>   500      8:00 
>   600      8:10 
>   800      8:30 
>   50        8:45 
>   100      8:55 
>   80       9:05

I need to create a variable in the database m (the variable t) that was equal to the sum of the elements in the column Total from the database m2 when the Hour2 in this database would be superior than the Hour + 5 minutes and would be inferior than the Hour - 5 minutes.

For example

For the entity a in m, the hour is 8:00
So I want to sum the Total of all the elements in m2 when the hour is between 7:55 and 8:05, in the example it would be 5602.

I want that my result would be:

> Entity     Code     Hour       t
>   a             3024            8:00     5602  
>   b             3024            8:05     1100
>   c             2111            8:11     600
>   d             2111            8:18     0
>   e             2111            8:33     800
>   f             2111            8:50     150
>   g             2111            9:08     80

I tried the following code

```
m<-mutate(m, t=sum(select(m2[Hour+300 >= m2$Hour & Hour-300 
  <= m2$Hour,],Total)))<br><br>
```

but is not working it returns a wrong value.

Then I decided to make a code with a for sentence:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(m)){
  Hour2<-m$Hour[i]
  m$t[i]<-sum(select(filter(m2,Hour>=Hour2-300, Hour<=Hour2+300),Total))  
}
```

The code works well buy it is too slow :/, I need to run the code several times so I am looking for a better way to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow. Please provide a reproducible example of both the code and the data.

Here is how is can by done.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

#Define Data
data = data.frame(Entity =c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g"), 
                  Code = c(3024,3024,2111,2111,2111,2111,2111),
                  Hour = c("8:00","8:05","8:11","8:18","8:33","8:50","9:08"))

data2 = data.frame(Total = c(102,5000,500,600,800,50,100,80),
                   Hour2 = c("7:55","7:58","8:00","8:10","8:30","8:45","8:55","9:05"))

#Create a dummy variable so that we can perform a cross join
data_dummy = data%>%
  mutate(dummy = 1)

data2_dummy = data2%>%
  mutate(dummy = 1)

# Cross join the data and create lead and lag times
final_df = data_dummy%>%
  inner_join(data2_dummy,by = "dummy")%>%
  select(-dummy)%>%
  mutate(Hour = hm(Hour),
         Hour2 = hm(Hour2))%>%
  mutate(HourLag = hms(Hour - hms("00:05:00"),roll = T),
         HourLead = hms(Hour + hms("00:05:00"),roll = T)
         )

#Filter by the condition
final_df = final_df[final_df$Hour2 >= final_df$HourLag,]
final_df = final_df[final_df$Hour2 <= final_df$HourLead,]


#Join the the original dataset (Not required)

final_df = final_df%>%
  group_by(Entity)%>%
  summarise(Total_sum = sum(Total))%>%
  inner_join(data,by = "Entity")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `fuzzyjoin` to join on time intervals

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)
fuzzy_full_join(
    m %>% mutate(
        Hour = as.POSIXct(Hour, format = "%H:%M"),
        Hour.min = Hour - as.difftime(5, unit = "mins"),
        Hour.max = Hour + as.difftime(5, unit = "mins")),
    m2 %>% mutate(Hour2 = as.POSIXct(Hour2, format = "%H:%M")),
    by = c("Hour.min" = "Hour2", "Hour.max" = "Hour2"),
    match_fun = list(`<=`, `>=`)) %>%
    select(-Hour.min, -Hour.max) %>%
    group_by(Entity, Code, Hour) %>%
    summarise(Total = sum(Total)) %>%
    mutate(Total = replace_na(Total, 0))
## A tibble: 7 x 4
## Groups:   Entity, Code [7]
#  Entity  Code Hour                Total
#  <fct>  <int> <dttm>              <dbl>
#1 a       3024 2019-02-16 08:00:00  5602
#2 b       3024 2019-02-16 08:05:00  1100
#3 c       2111 2019-02-16 08:11:00   600
#4 d       2111 2019-02-16 08:18:00     0
#5 e       2111 2019-02-16 08:33:00   800
#6 f       2111 2019-02-16 08:50:00   150
#7 g       2111 2019-02-16 09:08:00    80
```

Explanation: We create new columns `Hour.max` and `Hour.min` as `m$Hour` ± 5 minutes, and then perform a `fuzzy_full_join` subject to `m$Hour.min <=  m2$Hour2` and `m$Hour.max >= m2$Hour2`; the last step is a simple summarisation of `Total` by `Entity`, `Code` and `Hour`.

---

### Sample data

```
m <- read.table(text =
    "Entity   Code   Hour
a      3024     8:00
b      3024     8:05
c      2111     8:11
d        2111     8:18
e      2111     8:33
f       2111     8:50
g      2111     9:08", header = T)

m2 <- read.table(text =
    "Total    Hour2
102     7:55
5000    7:58
500     8:00
600     8:10
800     8:30
50      8:45
100     8:55
80      9:05 ", header = T)
```